How to run cronjob inside a distroless container?
I am trying to add a cronjob inside a distroless container that is running the application. It is either giving error or not running correctly. How can get this working as I want to create a cronjob that runs a shell script & a python script.
This is the Dockerfile I'm using:
# Base image for building the application
FROM docker.io/debian:12-slim AS build

# Set Python environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# Create directory for Gunicorn logs
RUN mkdir -p /app/logs/gunicorn

# Install necessary dependencies and libraries
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install --no-install-suggests --no-install-recommends --yes \
    python3-venv python3-dev default-libmysqlclient-dev build-essential \
    libmariadb-dev pkg-config wget curl gnupg2 unzip cron \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Set up Python virtual environment
RUN python3 -m venv /pypi/venv && \
    /pypi/venv/bin/pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel

# Copy crontab
COPY web/crontab /etc/cron.d/crontab
RUN chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/crontab
RUN touch /var/log/cron.log

# Install Python dependencies
FROM build AS build-venv
COPY web/requirements.txt /requirements.txt
RUN /pypi/venv/bin/pip install --disable-pip-version-check -r /requirements.txt pymysql wfastcgi gunicorn gevent

# Final stage: Set up the runtime environment
FROM gcr.io/distroless/python3-debian11

# Copy necessary files from previous stages
COPY --from=build-venv /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
COPY --from=build-venv /pypi/venv /pypi/venv
COPY --from=build-venv /app/logs /app/logs
COPY --from=build /etc/cron.d/crontab /etc/cron.d/crontab
COPY --from=build /var/log/cron.log /var/log/cron.log

# Set environment variables
ENV PYTHONPATH=web:$PYTHONPATH

# Copy application code
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app


# Start Gunicorn
ENTRYPOINT ["cron", "&&", "/pypi/venv/bin/gunicorn", "web.APP.wsgi:application", "--bind", "0.0.0.0:8000", "--access-logfile", "/app/logs/gunicorn/access.log", "--error-logfile", "/app/logs/gunicorn/error.log", "--log-level", "info"]

Also tried using a entrypoint.sh script:
#!/bin/sh

# Start gunicorn in background
/pypi/venv/bin/gunicorn web.APP.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 --access-logfile /app/logs/gunicorn/access.log --error-logfile /app/logs/gunicorn/error.log --log-level info  &

# Run periodic task
while true; do
    python3 web/cron_script.py
    sleep 300  # Run every 5 minutes
done

But with this also, I don't see the cron_script running.

Distroless containers don't include a shell and so you can't run shell scripts. Your alternative ENTRYPOINT uses the exec form ([...]) so you can't use && and you can't use the shell form because you don't have a shell. Perhaps add an init system?

Any alternative approach you can suggest to achieve this requirement?

If you want the services a full distro would supply, why have you chosen distroless?

I'd expect the various recipes in How to run a cron job inside a docker container? to work, up to the points others have mentioned about a distroless container not necessarily having a shell or a cron daemon.  Of note I'd run the cron daemon in its own container and not try to run (and manage) two processes in the same container.
